# What tools to test the reliability and stability of a newly built PC?

Tags: computer-building, benchmarking, stress-test

Just curious what everyone uses to stress test their machines.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best computer "burn-in" or stability testing software?](http://superuser.com/questions/8593/what-is-the-best-computer-burn-in-or-stability-testing-software)

Answer (score 5):

[Memtest86](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memtest86) - memory test software designed to test and stress test an x86 architecture computer's random access memory (RAM) for errors.

Comment: Memtest86 is usually not enough to test RAM for real. In most cases, the motherboard can supply stable enough voltage to the RAM that even a bit flaky RAM chips do work. Prime95 (or `mprime`) is a better choice because it puts serious CPU load in the same time. I'd suggest running some very demanding HDD benchmark in paraller to maximize the system load.

Answer (score 3):

[IntelBurnTest](http://downloads.guru3d.com/IntelBurnTest-v2.3-download-2047.html). Pushes your CPU to its max and fills the RAM as well. It's a good tool to make sure that your computer can handle a full load.

Answer (score 3):

[prime95](http://www.mersenne.org/freesoft/) ,it's widely used for stress testing both the CPU and the RAM

Answer (score 2):

I've used to get the highest temperatures with [OCCT](http://www.ocbase.com/perestroika_en/). If you would also want to test GPU stability, [FurMark](http://www.ozone3d.net/benchmarks/fur/) is very good.

Answer (score 1):

The aptly-named [BurnInTest](http://www.passmark.com/products/bit.htm) from PassMark is free for 30 days (which should be enough for one PC!).

Answer (score 0):

These software solutions are too unnatural. This is how they test in labs, and it would not surprise if one will ever find hickups with these tests. With any Intel processor, you cannot kill the processor, even if you have bad ventilation. I would say: use it!. And have your 4 year old kid use it. That is a much better stress test.

Comment: This is apparently how Intel tested some of their Pentium III models. </sarcasm>

Comment: Computers are *designed to run software* and to test the stability of the system, running some demanding software is a great way to verify that the system works as designed. Make sure to use some software that really pushes the hardware *and* checks the results. Prime95 (or `mprime`) would be once choice for CPU and RAM testing.